# Sass compass custom output file name

Tags: css, sass, compass

I have a inner.scss file, I would like to set custom name to output file, "mobile.css" for example.

My config.rb file:

```
preferred_syntax = :sass
http_path = '/'
css_dir = 'mobile/style'
sass_dir = 'mobile/sass'
images_dir = 'media'
javascripts_dir = 'scripts'
relative_assets = true
line_comments = true
# output_style = :compressed
```